# fetching newly added data from Oracle using python

Tags: python, sql, oracle

I'm trying to retrieve a newly added data from Oracle DB using Python.  I added the data using a web form and it has more field than what I've in the query below. Let say order date, ship date, etc.

I got this far with it, but not sure if the beginning itself is correct and I'm stuck here.  Not sure how to check the returned data is what I'm actually looking for.  How do i do that?

```
db = DBConnection.connect_to_intraday_db()
cursor = db.cursor()
query1 = cursor.execute("Select * from PORTFOLIO_ORDER where SYMBOL = 'TOP' and ORDER_QUANTITY = 200 and AVERAGE_PRICE = 56.99")
query1 = cursor.fetchone()
print query1
```

Devu

Comment: This is not a question. If you added data but it doesn't show up when you query it, then you probably failed to commit your transaction.

Comment: If you're to execute this query straight in mysqlplus/mysqldb or somewhere other, does it returns a result?

Comment: it returns the value. I can see that it's returning a value that i'm looking for when I do it manually.  I'm sitting here and verifying it.  when I run the automation how do I verify that it is actually returning something that I'm looking for.  That is actually my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cx_Oracle cursor return tuples.
So if you want to compare in python, you have to do it in python
for example:

```
 if  query1[0] == myFirstColumnValue:
     # Good tuple
```

and so on